# How to log into single stream with awslogs driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS and using aws log driver for centralized logging.
Below is the snippet of my log configuration.

```
"logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "app-test",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "spring-boot-app"
                }
            }
```

I have multiple instances of the service, hence multiple tasks. Logs are getting logged into cloudwatch but unexpectedly multiple streams are getting created (one per task id).

[image]

Is there a way to configure aws log driver so that all the logs of single service would be logged into the single stream instead of them being spread across multiple streams?

Answer (score 0):

No.  A log stream can have only one writer at a time (one process), which is enforced by the CloudWatch Logs API; see the [CloudWatch Logs documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatchLogsConcepts.html) and the [`awslogs` driver documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/awslogs/#awslogs-stream).  You can group the logs that you'd like to process together into a log group.